# Selecting a file from a list

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I select files one by one from a list and work on them? This is my code:

```
list=$( find $path \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cc" \) )
for file in "$list"
do
done
```

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do but the -exec flag in find may be beneficial to you.

Comment: I collect every file with these extensions and then move them one-by-one to another destination.. But some filenames contain whitespace.. How can i use -exec here?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to `find` as many commands as you like:

```
find $path \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cc" \) \
    -exec bash -c "echo cmd1 '{}'; echo cmd2 '{}'; echo etc." \;
```

an alternative is to write a function:

```
function safe_copy() {
  echo "$1"     
}          

export -f safe_copy

find $path \( -name "*.c" -or -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.cxx" -or -name "*.cc" \) \
     -exec bash -c "safe_copy '{}'" \;
```

You can also write a script and call it with exec instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-print0` as `find` argument, to print a `null` delimited stream of filenames.

Then loop read the `null` delimited stream.

```sh
find "$path" \( -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.cxx' -or -name '*.cc' \) -print0 |
while IFS= read -r file
do
done
```